# Asp.Net Core 3.1 Appsettings not respecting JsonConverter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, application-settings, jsonconverter

In asp.net core 3.1, using the new System.Text.Json, I am trying to use a custom JsonConverter on an appsettings section.  Manually serializing/deserializing respects the converter just fine, but reading from appSettings via Options pattern does not.  Here's what I have:

The JsonConverter.  For simplicity, this one just converts a string value to uppercase:

```
    public class UpperConverter : JsonConverter<string>
    {
        public override string Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
            reader.GetString().ToUpper();

        public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, string value, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
            writer.WriteStringValue(value == null ? "" : value.ToUpper());
    }
```

The appsettings class, declaring the converter on a string property:

```
    public class MyOptions
    {
        public const string Name = "MyOptions";
        [JsonConverter(typeof(UpperConverter))]
        public string MyString { get; set; }
    }
```

The Startup.cs changes to prepare everything:

```
       public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews()
                .AddJsonOptions(options =>
                {
                    options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new UpperConverter());
                });

            services.Configure<MyOptions>(Configuration.GetSection(MyOptions.Name));
        }
```

When I inject an `IOptions<MyOptions>` into the HomeController, it reads a lowercase value.  If I manually do `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyOptions>("{\"MyString\":\"lowercase_manual\"}")`, I get an uppercase string.  Even when I remove Startup declarations of JsonSerializerOptions.

Does anyone know how to get the appsettings / options pattern to respect the JsonConverter?  Do I have to declare the JsonSerializerOptions somewhere else?  Thanks.

Comment: They aren't meant to, nor do they have to. The JsonConverter options apply to ASP.NET request and response parsing. The Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration is a separate package used by *all* types of projects, including console projects. `appsettings.json` isn't a special file, it's just the conventional name used to load settings using one of the many available configuration providers. The JSON provider loads setting using a specific format, described in the docs. *All* settings, no matter the source (json, ini, database, environment), are stored as key/value pairs.

Comment: Why do you want to use a JsonConverter? You can't use it to construct objects, those are constructed from the key/value pairs loaded from all providers. If you want to convert the loaded values to uppercase - why? If case matters, shouldn't you be preserving case, or making sure the *correct* case was stored? If it doesn't you can use case-insensitive comparisons or case-insensitive dictionaries for those values

Comment: If you want to load settings in a specific way you can create your own settings provider. I suspect the real problem is the need for uppercase though

Comment: If you require upper-case settings, you need to apply the conversion to *all* settings, no matter the source. This means you should convert the values during binding, not during loading from one specific provider. Better yet, why not change `MyString`'s setter to store the value as uppercase?

Comment: No I don't require uppercase, it was just a simple thing to do in a converter for this question.  Your first comment about the intended use of extensions is helpful, as is the comment about creating my own settings provider.

Comment: *Why*? You probably don't need one, unless you have an external file that doesn't follow the `section:subsection:key:value` form. Every custom provider should convert settings to that form though.

Comment: I guess the specific answer I was looking for here is that JsonConfigurationProvider never calls ```JsonSerializer.Deserialize```, because as you point out it doesn't need to, it's just for creating key-value pairs.  It calls ```JsonDocument.Parse``` for that work instead.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's important to understand that the [options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options) is implemented as two separate steps: reading data from a configuration source, then binding that data to strongly-typed objects.

The read step is implemented by various configuration providers, only one of which is JSON. You might expect that the JSON provider would respect your `JsonConverter`, but this step only performs minimal transformation of its configuration data into a generic format that the next step can accept.

The binding step, then, would seem to be the place that would care about `JsonConverter`. But this step is intentionally completely agnostic of any specific configuration provider, because it simply receives data in a generic format from the providers **of which it purposefully knows nothing about**. Therefore, it won't care about a JSON-specific converter.

It will, however, care about more generic converters to handle its generic data, and fortunately .NET already has infrastructure for this built in: [type converters](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverter). These have been in .NET since almost the beginning, and while they're old they're perfectly simple, serviceable, and indeed ideal for this specific scenario.

A full example of how to implement a type converter is out of scope for this answer, but the essentials are that you derive from `TypeConverter`, override the appropriate methods, and decorate the class you want to be converted with a [`TypeConverterAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverterattribute) pointing back to your `TypeConverter` implementation. Then it should all Just Work™.

---

The caveat with the example you've provided is that you aren't actually trying to **convert** anything, you're trying to **transform** a string, and obviously a `TypeConverter` won't be invoked since the source value from the configuration providers is a string, while the destination type on your options class is also a string.

What you can do instead is create a new class that wraps a string to force it to uppercase:

```cs
public class UppercaseString
{
    public string Value { get; }

    public UppercaseString(string str)
    {
        Value = str.ToUpper();
    }

    public static implicit operator string(UppercaseString upper)
        => upper.Value;
}
```

then change your options class to use that wrapper:

```cs
public class MyOptions
{
    public const string Name = "MyOptions";

    public UppercaseString MyString { get; set; }
}
```

and finally, implement a `TypeConverter` that converts from `string` to `UppercaseString`.

Note the definition of `implicit operator string` - this allows you to use an `UppercaseString` anywhere a standard `string` is expected, so that you don't have to change your code that references `MyOptions.MyString` to `MyOptions.MyString.Value`.

Comment: That idea of value wrapping is fenomenal. Thank you very much.