# Writing a custom converter for appsettings.json

Tags: c#, appsettings, jsonconverter

I want to create an appsettings.json converter which converts `Symbols` to `IReadOnlyCollection<Symbol>`. The converter should split the string by `/`, which will result into a BaseAsset/QuoteAsset. It should then check whether `QuoteAsset` equals to `StakeCurrency` or not. If it doesn't, throw an exception. What is the best way to do that with a custom converter? I don't want to use binding. Is it possible to use a custom JsonConverter?

- appsettings.json

```
{
  "BacktestConfiguration": {
    "StakeCurrency": "USDT",
    "Symbols": [ "TRX/USDT", "BTC/USDT", "ETH/USDT" ]
  }
}
```

- Classes

```cs
public class BacktestOptions
{
    public const string Position = "BacktestConfiguration";

    public string StakeCurrency { get; set; }
    public IReadOnlyCollection<Symbol> Symbols { get; set; }
}

public class Symbol
{
    public string BaseAsset { get; set; }
    public string QuoteAsset { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a custom JsonConverter to handle the transformation from the Array of strings to a `IReadOnlyCollection<Symbol>`.

Decorate the `Symbols` property of the `BacktestOptions` class with the converter Type and handle the conversion in the custom converter's `Read()` method, where you split the strings in the array to generate new `Symbol` objects with the parts.
Then return a new `ReadOnlyCollection<Symbol>` from the generated list of `Symbol` objects.

I'm using a *handler* class, `BacktestConfigurationHandler`, to contain the objects and provide the base conversion and deserialization functionality.

Call the static `Deserialize()` method, passing the JSON as argument.
It returns a `BacktestConfiguration` object when there's no mismatch between the StakeCurrency value and any of the Symbol[].QuoteAsset values.
It throws a `JsonException` in case there's a mismatch.

Call it as:

```
var configuration = BacktestConfigurationHandler.Deserialize(json);
```

**`BacktestConfigurationHandler` class**:

► It handles deserialization only. The serialization, as you can see, is not implemented: the `Write()` method does nothing.

```
public class BacktestConfigurationHandler
{
    public class BacktestRoot {
        public BacktestConfiguration BacktestConfiguration { get; set; }
    }

    public class BacktestConfiguration
    {
        public const string Position = "BacktestConfiguration";

        public string StakeCurrency { get; set; }

        [JsonConverter(typeof(SymbolConverter))]
        public IReadOnlyCollection<Symbol> Symbols { get; set; }
    }

    public class Symbol
    {
        public Symbol() : this("", "") { }
        public Symbol(string baseAsset, string quoteAsset) {
            BaseAsset = baseAsset;
            QuoteAsset = quoteAsset;
        }

        public string BaseAsset { get; set; }
        public string QuoteAsset { get; set; }
    }

    public static BacktestConfiguration Deserialize(string json)
    {
        var root = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<BacktestRoot>(json);
        var stakeCurrency = root.BacktestConfiguration.StakeCurrency;
        if (root.BacktestConfiguration.Symbols.Any(s => s.QuoteAsset != stakeCurrency)) {
            throw new JsonException("StakeCurrency mismatch");
        }
        return root.BacktestConfiguration;
    }

    public class SymbolConverter : JsonConverter<IReadOnlyCollection<Symbol>>
    {
        public override IReadOnlyCollection<Symbol> Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.StartArray) {
                var symbols = new List<Symbol>();
                var values = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<string[]>(ref reader, options);

                foreach (string value in values) {
                    var parts = value.Split('/');
                    symbols.Add(new Symbol(parts[0], parts[1]));

                }
                return new ReadOnlyCollection<Symbol>(symbols);
            }
            return null;

        public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, IReadOnlyCollection<Symbol> value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
            => throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
Try these variations of the class Model and the adapted custom converters, both a JSON converter and a TypeConverter assigned to the Symbols Property.

I've tested the converters in a base scenario, converting from JSON to a class model directly and accessing / casting the objects using the implicit operators called by the TypeConverter.

```
public class BacktestOptionsRoot
{
    public BacktestOptions BacktestConfiguration { get; set; }
}

public class BacktestOptions
{
    public const string Position = "BacktestConfiguration";

    public string StakeCurrency { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonSymbolConverter))]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(BacktestSymbolsConverter))]
    public BacktestSymbols Symbols { get; set; }
}

public class Symbol
{
    public Symbol() : this("", "") { }
    public Symbol(string baseAsset, string quoteAsset)
    {
        BaseAsset = baseAsset;
        QuoteAsset = quoteAsset;
    }

    public string BaseAsset { get; set; }
    public string QuoteAsset { get; set; }
}

public class BacktestSymbolsConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(string[])) {
            return (BacktestSymbols)(value as string[]);
        }
        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        if (value is BacktestSymbols) {
            return (string[])(value as BacktestSymbols);
        }
        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }
}

public class JsonSymbolConverter : JsonConverter<BacktestSymbols>
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert)
    {
        return typeToConvert == typeof(BacktestSymbols);
    }

    public override BacktestSymbols Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.StartArray) {
            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<string[]>(ref reader, options);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, BacktestSymbols value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}


public class BacktestSymbols
{
    public ReadOnlyCollection<Symbol> Value { get; }
    public string[] Symbols => Value.Select(v => $"{v.BaseAsset}/{v.QuoteAsset}").ToArray();

    public BacktestSymbols(string[] source)
    {
        var symbols = new List<Symbol>();

        if (source != null && source.Length > 0) {
            foreach (string value in source) {
                var parts = value.Split('/');
                symbols.Add(new Symbol(parts[0], parts[1]));
            }
        }
        Value = new ReadOnlyCollection<Symbol>(symbols);
    }

    public static implicit operator BacktestSymbols(string[] source) => new BacktestSymbols(source);
    public static implicit operator string[](BacktestSymbols instance) => instance.Symbols;
    public override string ToString() => $"[ {string.Join(",", Symbols)} ]";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That means the `services.Configure<BacktestOptions>(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection(BacktestOptions.Backtest))` can't make it automatically?

Comment: Yes, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62820147/asp-net-core-3-1-appsettings-not-respecting-jsonconverter. I want something like `public static implicit operator string(UppercaseString upper)
        => upper.Value;`, which automatically converts it. Basically, once I DI the `Options<T>`, it should resolve it automatically.

Comment: I've added a modified class Model and JSON / Type Converters. Give it a look. I'm not sure it can work in the scenario you described.

Comment: Thank you for the effort you've put! During that time I made a more specific question, which I resolved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66553181/asp-net-core-5-doesnt-respect-neither-jsonconverter-nor-typeconverter - you can have a look. `TypeConverter` works well itself without the `implicit` converter but its attribute should be placed above the Symbol class instead, not in the BacktestOptions. I'm accepting the answer now and thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Here is an extension method that can be used as a helper that works with JsonConverters.

It checks if a class has the [Serializable] attribute. If the attribute is not present, it tries to get the configuration section using the default method. If the class has the [Serializable] attribute, the method uses the custom deserialization logic to convert the section into a JSON string and deserialize it to the requested type.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.Json;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace Common.Extensions;

public static class ConfigurationExtensions
{
    public static T GetConfig<T>(this IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var type = typeof(T);

        var isSerializable = type.IsDefined(typeof(SerializableAttribute), false);

        if (!isSerializable)
            return configuration.GetSection(typeof(T).Name).Get<T>() ??
                   throw new Exception($"Could not find {typeof(T).Name} in configuration");

        var section = configuration.GetRequiredSection(typeof(T).Name);
        var json = ConvertSectionToJson(section);
        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(json)!;
    }

    private static string ConvertSectionToJson(IConfigurationSection section)
    {
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        FillDictionaryFromSection(dictionary, section);

        return JsonSerializer.Serialize(dictionary);

    }

    private static void FillDictionaryFromSection(Dictionary<string, object> dictionary, IConfigurationSection section)
    {
        foreach (var child in section.GetChildren())
        {
            if (child.GetChildren().Any())
            {
                var nestedDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                FillDictionaryFromSection(nestedDictionary, child);
                dictionary.Add(child.Key, nestedDictionary);
            }
            else
            {
                dictionary.Add(child.Key, child.Value ?? string.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
}
```