# ASP.NET Core 5 doesn't respect neither JsonConverter nor TypeConverter

Tags: c#, .net-5, typeconverter, asp.net-core-5.0, jsonconverter

The title is pretty self explanatory. ASP.NET Core 5 doesn't respect neither the JsonConverter nor the TypeConverter.

The symbols e.g. `"TRX/USDT"` should be split by `/` and converted to `new Symbol("TRX", "USDT")` as I already did that. Basically, I want `services.Configure<BacktestOptions>(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection(BacktestOptions.Backtest))` to resolve it automatically.

`public IReadOnlyCollection<string> Symbols { get; set; }` works fine, but `public IReadOnlyCollection<Symbol> Symbols { get; set; }` doesn't, because it doesn't recognize the converter class.

This question [Asp.Net Core 3.1 Appsettings not respecting JsonConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62820147/asp-net-core-3-1-appsettings-not-respecting-jsonconverter), the guy who answered it, states that TypeConverter should work.

#### appsettings.json

```
{
  "Backtest": {
    "StartBalance": 1000, 
    "StakeCurrency": "USDT",
    "Symbols": [ "TRX/USDT", "BTC/USDT", "ETH/USDT" ]
  }
}
```

#### Snippet

```cs
public class Symbol
{
    public Symbol()
    {
    }

    public Symbol(string baseAsset, string quoteAsset)
    {
        BaseAsset = baseAsset;
        QuoteAsset = quoteAsset;
    }

    public string BaseAsset { get; set; }
    public string QuoteAsset { get; set; }
}

public class BacktestOptions
{
    public const string Backtest = "Backtest";
    
    [Required]
    [Range(100, 50000)]
    public decimal StartBalance { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$")]
    public string StakeCurrency { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(SymbolConverter))]
    public IReadOnlyCollection<Symbol> Symbols { get; set; }
}

public class SymbolConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context,
        Type sourceType)
    {
        if (sourceType == typeof(string))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }
    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context,
        CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        if (value is string v)
        {
            var parts = v.Split('/');

            return new Symbol(parts[0], parts[1]);
        }

        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }
}
```

#### Additionally, JsonConverter example

```cs
public class SymbolConverter : JsonConverter<IReadOnlyCollection<Symbol>>
{
    public override IReadOnlyCollection<Symbol> Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert,
        JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.StartArray)
        {
            var values = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<string[]>(ref reader, options);

            var symbols = values.Select(value => value.Split('/')).Select(parts => new Symbol(parts[0], parts[1])).ToList();

            return new ReadOnlyCollection<Symbol>(symbols);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, IReadOnlyCollection<Symbol> value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Comment: The title is not really self-explanatory but anyway... It doesn't explicitly state it but it would seem [TypeConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverter?view=net-5.0) is only valid for decorating the class and not properties, which [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50839232/3034273) also seems to suggest. Perhaps try to decorate the `Symbol` class instead?

Comment: @Xerillio, damn mate, you were right. It worked by putting the TypeConverter over the Symbol class.

Comment: @Xerillio, you can type that as an answer. Also, do you think that there is a way to make `JsonConvert` work with it?

Comment: It's more of a duplicate question though :) No, sadly I don't know but it seems from the question you linked that it's intentionally not considering that converter type. I suggest trying to ask on the [dotnet projects GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime)

Comment: @Xerillio, thank you!

Comment: [tag:asp.net-core-5.0] uses [tag:system.text.json] for JSON serialization by default, and this serializer does not support typeconverters.  See: [System.Text.Json does not support TypeConverters #38812](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/38812).  If you want a JSON serializer that supports typeconverters you need to revert back to Json.NET, see [Where did IMvcBuilder AddJsonOptions go in .Net Core 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55666898/3744182).

Comment: @dbc, I'm currently using a TypeConverter. You state that I would be able to use a JsonConverter that way? I'm also using the Host.CreateBuilder, not WebHost which ASP.NET Core uses. I don't have controllers. As far as I'm aware, the NuGet is only for Mvc?